# How to Use MySQL Database in Netbeans without using MySql Software

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm developing a little Java application in netbeans. I'm using MySql Database in this application, but if i want to connect my application to the database then I have to install the MySql software on every Computer and that's time consuming and making my application complicated.

Is there any other way to use any plug-in or something in Netbeans so that i don't have to install the MySql community application on every computer to access the database.

Comment: You can have database running only on a single system. you can call it as *MySQL Server*. You have to grant connections permission to the systems on which your java app is running.

Comment: This might be helpful if you want to manage/access MySql server database using Netbeans IDE.  [Check this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote database on a server and use [JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) library to connect to to your db

I did smth like that:

```
public class MySqlConnector {

// JDBC driver name and database URL
private final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
private String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project1";

//  Database credentials
private String USER = "admin";
private String PASS = "admin";

public void connectDB() {

    try {

          //Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
    } catch(SQLException se) {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you said is possible in development but definitely that's not possible in production phase, since every computer has its own MySQL they are completely ignored about changes of each other, you have to have single computer with MySQL installed and every computer should be connected to that, that's called MySQL server.

Btw that has nothing to do with netbeans, netbeans is just an IDE it's helpful but it can not do magic things the data should be stored in database